# I am fetching data from an api for getting stats of corona virus and wanted to plot a pie chart for it but pie chart is accepting only double values

Tags: flutter, exception, dart, pie-chart, nosuchmethoderror

I am  fetching data from an api for getting stats of corona virus and wanted to plot a pie chart for it but pie chart is accepting only double values. Please Help

```
 class PiechartFunction extends StatelessWidget {

 final Map worlddata;

 const PiechartFunction({Key key, this.worlddata}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return PieChart(
    dataMap: {
      'Confirmed' : worlddata['confirmed'].toDouble(),
      'Active' : worlddata['confirmed'].toDouble(),
      'Recovered' : worlddata['confirmed'].toDouble(),
      'Death' : worlddata['confirmed'].toDouble(),
    });
}
}


════════ Exception caught by widgets library 
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building PiechartFunction(dirty):
The method 'toDouble' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toDouble()
```

Comment: Can you print and check if any of your `worlddata` is null. Because from your error log `toDouble` is getting called on null.

Comment: No i was not able to print the data because i have not passed the index value to my list builder...................Thanks for help @shubham